# InvocationTargetException occured : null in Play framework

Tags: java, error-handling, playframework

I'm using play framework for my application 
In my application.conf i have given

```
jvm.memory=-Xmx512M -Xms512M -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

I have a function which will be executed for every Customer and for  customers each microapp
This function will return records for that customer and for that microapp from DB.

if i run for all customer I'm getting InvocationTargetException for 16th customer.(For 15 customers it ran successfully).

The error is

```
12:38:30,153 ERROR ~ 


Execution exception
InvocationTargetException occured : null

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:230)
        at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:543)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:499)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:475)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:470)
        at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:158)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.StringValue.from(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.String.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SingleByteCharsetConverter.toString(SingleByteCharsetConverter.java:327)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetRow.getString(ResultSetRow.java:787)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.BufferRow.getString(BufferRow.java:539)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5571)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5448)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5488)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarcharTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarcharTypeDescriptor.java:61)
        at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:64)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:249)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:229)
        at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:330)
        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2283)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1527)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1455)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1355)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:611)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:829)
        at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:274)
```

I found there is something error with that customer . so i run for that customer alone. I'm getting

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.read(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.Manifest.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getManifest(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:633)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "pool-2-thread-1" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space


For this microapp( Error occuring ) alone i have 421,251 records
```

What could be the source of error. Please help me.

Comment: Is there a deadlock happening because of long running tasks?

Comment: @basav Yes it finally hang up whole system. So i increased my jvm config as     jvm.memory=-Xmx1096M -Xms1096M -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit  After that i restarted my machine. Again same error occurred with different customer(56th customer)
While the process starts, usage of ram is 647.8MB when the error starts came it was 1.7GB of usage, my ram capacity is 2 GB. I have really huge data. It ends heap space exception in the terminal and it continuously executing.....

Comment: Then you have to process in chunks, spawn only required number of threads or use a queue system

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an OutOfMemory error. It happens later when you increase the ram for that reason.

You did not provide any code sample, but I assume you are trying to load into memory too much data from your clients with only one query. That comment about having 421k records kind of confirms this (unless I misunderstood).

Instead of doing a find() (or select, or the cal you are doing) to retrieve all the records, try to retrieve records in batches (100, 200) and process them that way.